# How to disable the change of the post modification date when updating a post in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

When we perform a change in a post Wordpress modification date is updated, I need to disable this date of modification, when any modification is made in a post. I reviewed the code but can not find how to disable this option.

Answer (score 1):

Never change core WordPress files or folders; you will break things, and you will also loose changes when WordPress updates.

Search for plugins for needed functions: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ Like https://wordpress.org/plugins/stealth-update/

Comment: I have reviewed and must be selected each time you wish to disable updating of date, I want this to be automatic. Avoid selecting anything.